# Using multiprocessing.Pool in a class on Windows with IPython Notebook

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have written a class method to produce multiple instances of a second class using `multiprocessing.Pool` (see below). Using IPython, this works on Linux/OSX but not on Windows (it will hang). So my question; is it possible, and what is the most succinct way, to alter my code so that this works on Windows? (Edit: it appears to be a problem specific to IPython Notebook)

I have read numerous posts about the issues with Windows lacking `fork()` and the need for `if __name__ == "__main__":`, but I'm unclear how to implement that in this instance, if I'm using IPython Notebook.

Thanks in advance, Chris.

**my_class_factory.py**

```
import multiprocessing

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a=1):
        self.a = a

def unpack_and_make_class(val_dict):
    if val_dict.has_key('args'):
        args = val_dict.pop('args')
    else:
        args = []            
    return MyClass(*args, **val_dict)

class MyClassFactory(object):

    def make_classes(self, inputs):

        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
        mapping = pool.map

        myclasses = mapping(unpack_and_make_class, inputs)

        pool.close()
        pool.join()

        return myclasses
```

then in IPython Notebook:

```
In [1]: from my_class_factory import MyClassFactory
In [2]: mcf = MyClassFactory()
In []: cls = mcf.make_classes([{'a':1}, {'a':2}, {'a':3}])
```

this will run in Linux/OSx but will hang in Windows with the error:

```
AssertionError: __main__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\chris\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\chris\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 488, in prepare
    assert main_name not in sys.modules, main_name
```

Comment: So what exactly is not working?

Comment: So, for example, in an IPython session `In [1]: mcf = MyClassFactory(); cls = mcf.make_classes([{'a':1}, {'a':2}, {'a':3}])` will happily run in Linux. But in Windows it will hang.

Comment: Can you add code that produces the error/hang?

Comment: I've just edited my question to reproduce the error, thanks

Comment: I tried this from an IPython terminal in windows and it worked fine.  Something may be wrong with your environment.

Comment: Ah thanks for trying, you're right, I just tested in an IPython terminal and it does work. I was actually running it in an IPython Notebook, so it appears the issue is specific to this. I will edit my question with this fact and the actual error that is propogating. Could you please try it again in the IPython Notebook and let me know if you get the same error?